# Why babel preset "env" does not transpile destructuring statements?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

In my code there is following statement:

```
const { a, b } = something;
```

My .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": { "node": "current" }
    }]
  ]
}
```

My node version: `4.6.1`.
babel-cli: `6.24.1`
babel-preset-env: `1.5.2`

After transpiling code, when I run it I get "Syntax error: unexpected token {":

```
const { a, b } = something
      ^
```

I seems that it does not transpile "destructuring code"...
I tried to add but it did not change anything:

```
"plugins": [
  "transform-es2015-destructuring"
]
```

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: If you explicitly put `"node": 4.6` does it work? Also can you post the full error with stacktrace?

Comment: I tried it on another pc and it works now. Then, on the pc on which it did not work I removed all node_modules and npm installed them again and it works now... strange but I guess it is solved...